# Remotely change the browsers page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome can be started with the `remote-debugging-port` option:

```
$ chromium-browser www.stackoverflow.com -remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Now lets say I started the remote browser on `192.168.0.10` I can create a tunnel to make a connection to port 9222 *(remote-debugging-port only listens on localhost)* from another machine.

```
$ ssh -f -L 3000:localhost:9222 192.168.0.10 -N
```

This means I can attach my local browser to the remote browsers development tools buy visiting `http://localhost:3000`. My goal is to change the webpage shown on the remote browser. I can achieve this by using the JavaScript console and setting `location.href=http://superuser.com` for example.

My question is, does Google Chrome have an API to achieve this so the URL can be set from the command line or a script?